# Have problem with my lambda function call to sns topic

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sdk

I am newbie to using AWS, but I am trying to send SMS from a lambda function by node js but it doesn't work.

My script is shown here:

```
import { SNS } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-config-service";

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Lambda function handler
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const sns = new AWS.SNS();

  // Get the current date and time in GMT+7
  const now = new Date();
  const gmt7Offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() + 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const gmt7Date = new Date(now.getTime() + gmt7Offset);

  // Generate random values for two dice rolls (between 1 and 6)
  const die1 = randomInt(1, 7);
  const die2 = randomInt(1, 7);

  // Format the date and time in GMT+7
  const dateTimeString = gmt7Date.toLocaleString();

  // Create the result string
  const result = `Giá trị khi tung 2 cục súc xắc ngẫu nhiên là ${die1} và ${die2}. Thời gian hiện tại là ${dateTimeString} (GMT+7).`;

  // Create the message parameters
  const messageParams = {
    Message: result,
    TopicArn: 'yarn:aws:sns:us-east-1:991676580242:Default_CloudWatch_Alarms_Topic:ff4f538e-5d7a-4394-871b-2c8716fa38aa' // Replace with your SNS topic ARN
  };

  // Publish the result to the SNS topic
  try {
    await sns.publish(messageParams).promise();
    console.log('Tin nhắn đã được gửi đến SNS thành công.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Lỗi khi gửi tin nhắn đến SNS:', error);
    throw error;
  }

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ result }),
  };

  return response;
};

// Random integer function
function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

I get this error:

> errorMessage: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Please help me fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `export const handler = ...` instead of `module.exports`.